# Grunt ( not written because src files were empty )

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    '_s/js/script.js': ['_s/components/js/*.js','_s/components/js/other.js']
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

files/

d- components  
   f- script.js ->
     function test(){
       return "Hello";
    }
d- css 
d- js
   script.js -> 

f- node_modules   
f- gruntfile.js 
f- index.html  
package.json
```

I'm write in file _s/components/js/script.js but when i'm try turn on in terminal command grunt uglify. i've been this error

```
>> Destination (_s/js/script.js) not written because src files were empty.

Done, without errors.
```

**Sorry! I'm decided my**

```
files: {
                    'js/script.js': ['components/js/*.js']
                }
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you have an `_s` folder.

Comment: petrov@petya:~/WebstormProjects/_s$ pwd
/home/petrov/WebstormProjects/_s

Comment: Yes, but you're running Grunt from within the `_s` folder, aren't you, so just remove the references to it.